# sh spanning treeコマンドの確認点

Tags: network

`sh spanning tree` コマンドで問題が発生していない事の確認として、問題が無いと言い切れる根拠はどう説明したらよろしいでしょうか

作業前に取得した `sh spanning tree` の情報と比較して、「ルートブリッジとしているinterfaceとフォワーディングとしているportに変更が無いかを確認する」という認識なのですが、間違っているのかもしれません

Comment: モノゴトの基本として、問題の無いことを証明することは不可能なので、満たすべき動作を網羅しているかを確認するという命題に落とし込む必要があります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コマンドはあくまで現在の状態を表示するだけなので、それだけでは｢問題がない｣ことは何も担保しません。作業前後で結果を比較していえるのは作業前後で状況が変化していない、ということだけです。

そのNWのあるべき姿と現在の状況を比較して一致していることを確認して初めて問題がないということができます。